# Weight implementation in graph

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the path between two vertices and their distance.
My implementation is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <string> v1 = {"Prague", "Helsinki", "Beijing", "Tokyo", "Jakarta","London", "New York"};
vector <int> w = {};
// A directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
class Graph {
    int V; // No. of vertices in graph
    list<int>* adj; // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
 
    // A recursive function used by printAllPaths()
    void printAllPathsUtil(int, int, bool[], int[], int&);
 
public:
    Graph(int V); // Constructor
    void addVertex(string name);
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int weight);
    void printAllPaths(int s, int d);
};
 
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}
void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int weight)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v); // Add v to u’s list.
    w.push_back(weight);
}
 
// Prints all paths from 's' to 'd'
void Graph::printAllPaths(int s, int d)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool* visited = new bool[V];
    // Create an array to store paths
    int* path = new int[V];
    int path_index = 0; // Initialize path[] as empty
 
    // Initialize all vertices as not visited
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
 
    // Call the recursive helper function to print all paths
    printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path, path_index);
}
 
// A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'.
// visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path.
// path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current
// index in path[]
void Graph::printAllPathsUtil(int u, int d, bool visited[],
                              int path[], int& path_index)
{
    // Mark the current node and store it in path[]
    visited[u] = true;
    path[path_index] = u;
    path_index++;
    int sum = 0;
    // If current vertex is same as destination, then print
    // current path[]
    if (u == d) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path_index; i++){
            sum += w[i];
            cout << v1[path[i]] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Total distance is: " << sum;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else // If current vertex is not destination
    {
        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
        list<int>::iterator i;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
            if (!visited[*i])
                printAllPathsUtil(*i, d, visited, path, path_index);
    }
 
    // Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited
    path_index--;
    visited[u] = false;
}
 
// Driver program
int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    Graph g(7);
       
    g.addEdge(0, 1, 1845);
    g.addEdge(0, 5, 1264);
    g.addEdge(1, 3, 7815);
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 8132); 
    g.addEdge(2, 6, 11550);
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 1303);
    g.addEdge(3, 4, 5782);
    g.addEdge(3, 6, 10838);
    g.addEdge(4, 2, 4616);
    g.addEdge(5, 3, 9566);
    g.addEdge(6, 5, 5567);
    int s = 0, d = 2;
    cout << "Following are all different paths from " << v1[s] << " to " << v1[d] << endl;
    g.printAllPaths(s, d);
 
    return 0;

}
```

Obviously this part is wrong:

```
vector <int> w = {};
w.push_back(weight);
    int sum = 0;
    // If current vertex is same as destination, then print
    // current path[]
    if (u == d) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path_index; i++){
            sum += w[i];
            cout << v1[path[i]] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Total distance is: " << sum;
        cout << endl;
```

Output is:

```
Prague Helsinki Tokyo Jakarta Beijing
Total distance is: 30606
Prague London Tokyo Jakarta Beijing
Total distance is: 30606
```

This is wrong (but the path is correct) because of my implementation, it prints out the summation of the overall first 5 weights. But I just did not understand how can I get the weights

How can I get the corresponding weights and add them up?

What I expect:

```
Prague Helsinki Tokyo Jakarta Beijing
Total distance is: 20058
Prague London Tokyo Jakarta Beijing
Total distance is: (There will be some number I have not calculated yet)
```

Comment: so I guess your problem is how to find the weight between a pair of nodes? The total weight should be Prague-London weight + London-Tokyo weight + Tokyo-Jakarta weight + Jakarta-Beijing weight

Comment: Weight between pair of nodes passed when addEdge() is called. Yes, the total weight should be as you said.

Comment: well for a start, the way you are storing the weights now makes it impossible to find the correct one.  Instead of "How can I get the weight?" you should be thinking of "How can I store the weights, so that I can get the right ones?"

Comment: I was thinking to push the weight whenever that edge is in the path, rather than pushing the weight when addEdge is called. But it did not work out too @user253751

Comment: If the question was this: "I have some numbers I need to look up: Prague->Helsinki=1845, Prague->London=1264, Helsinki->Tokyo=7815, ...etc... and the user can input Prague->London and the program has to print 1264." would you have any idea how to write the code?

Comment: I would use a dictionary if it was Python. {"Prague-Helsinki":1264} and get the value if the key is passed. Maybe you can do that in C++ too I don't know. I am a noob in C++ @user253751

Comment: The C++ version of a dictionary is `std::map`, but it's possible to make an inefficient dictionary using just vectors (or lists), and I am surprised you have not done that since I believe it is within your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems here. When you create the edges you do not coupled their cost to them in any way. Also when you traverse them in your algorithm you do not save the cost of traversing the edge, you only save the cities.

Here is a simple solution if you want to keep almost an identical structure. You can  accompany the adjecency lists with a list of the costs for each such edge. Son instead of having the `w` array you can have one such for each noce (city). Then the path array can also be accompanied by another int array with the costs of each step.

Starting with defining and creating the edges it would be:

```
class Graph {
    int V; // No. of vertices in graph
    list<int>* adj; // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
    list<int>* adj_weights; // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists

    ...

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
    adj_weights = new list<int>[V];
}
void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int weight)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v); // Add v to u’s list.
    adj_weights[u].push_back(weight); // Add the weight of the path as well.
}
```

Now we have stored the weights and the edges together in a better way, but we still need to use this in the algorithm. Here is an example change of the main functions:

```
// Prints all paths from 's' to 'd'
void Graph::printAllPaths(int s, int d)
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool* visited = new bool[V];
    // Create an array to store paths
    int* path = new int[V];
    int* path_costs = new int[V];
    int path_index = 0; // Initialize path[] and path_costs[] as empty
 
    // Initialize all vertices as not visited
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
 
    // Call the recursive helper function to print all paths
    // Note that we let cost = 0 since we don't have to move to the starting city
    printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path_costs, path, path_index, 0);
}
 
// A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'.
// visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path.
// path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current
// index in path[]
void Graph::printAllPathsUtil(int u, int d, bool visited[], int path_costs[],
                              int path[], int& path_index, int cost)
{
    // Mark the current node and store it in path[]
    visited[u] = true;
    path[path_index] = u;
    path_costs[path_index] = cost;   // Save cost of this step
    path_index++;
    int sum = 0;
    // If current vertex is same as destination, then print
    // current path[]
    if (u == d) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path_index; i++){
            sum += path_costs[i];   // Now add all the costs
            cout << v1[path[i]] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Total distance is: " << sum;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else // If current vertex is not destination
    {
        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to current vertex
        // Now we loop over both adj and adj_weights
        list<int>::iterator i, j;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(), j = adj_weights[u].begin();
             i != adj[u].end(); ++i, ++j)
            if (!visited[*i])
                printAllPathsUtil(*i, d, visited, path_costs, path, 
                                  path_index, *j);
    }
 
    // Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited
    path_index--;
    visited[u] = false;
}
```

You can see a full version of the augmented code here https://ideone.com/xGju0y and it gives the following output:

```
Following are all different paths from Prague to Beijing
Prague Helsinki Tokyo Jakarta Beijing 
Total distance is: 20058
Prague London Tokyo Jakarta Beijing 
Total distance is: 21228
```

I hope this helps! I tried to focus on using the same concepts you introduced to not solve things with some new classes or imports. But there are much nicer ways to solve this. One example is to merge the path and path_weights arrays into one array of pairs of ints, and to merge adj and adj_weights into an array of lists of pairs of ints instead of an array of lists of ints.

Comment: This solves the issue. Thank you very much! Also thanks a lot for the comprehensive explanation. I tried to solve this by using maps, for example, <edge, distance> for each pair. But I guess your solution is more efficient than that.

Comment: Nice! Yes, maps are also possile to use, and quite nice. But this way we don't have to do any map lookup calls, and we can save the info quite compactly.

Comment: Very good one, I really appreciate it! Also welcome to StackOverflow.